# The .css file turns to become an HTML (thymeleaf) where it was embedded to

Tags: java, html, css, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

This is weird but it looks like Spring has just turned the `bootstrap.css` file into the thymeleaf `.html` template. Just take a look at the screenshot:
[image: bootstrap.css appears to have the contents of the .html now...]

Can anyone explain me why this has happened and how to fix it? I have chacked and I'm sure that my `bootstrap.css` file is a normal Twitter-bootstrap CSS. The code of the panel.html template and Thymeleaf Java config are both below:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("views/localization");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

    templateResolver.setPrefix("views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);

    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("*").setViewName("panel");
    registry.setOrder(0);
}
```

And the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HBase listener</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{static/css/bootstrap.css}" media="all"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{img/ico.png}"/>

</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1 data-th-text="#{welcome.message}">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Today is: <span data-th-text="${#dates.format(standardDate, 'HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy')}">*_*</span></p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>555kjvd</h3>
            <p>Presved</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Preved</h3>
            <p>Preved</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Preved</h3>
            <p>Preved</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the folder structure:
[image: spring-boot app folder structure]

Comment: Could it be that the URL to the bootstrap.css is wrong? On the image I see it could be trying to load the url /panel/static/css/bootstrap.css?

Comment: Try using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">` instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{static/css/bootstrap.css}">` (or `bootstrap.min.css` or what have you); also for font awesome. The `@` character has special semantics in Thymeleaf you need to be aware of; cf <http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html>

Comment: @Brainfeeder do you mean my controller has made it?
`@RequestMapping(value = "/panel", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("standardDate", datesAndTimes.getInstance().getDate());
        return "panel";
    }`

Comment: I think so, yes. The controller might be okay, but the path it prints is relative. So the controller function for static is not triggered. Add a slash in front. It might help.

Comment: Use @{/static/css/bootstrap.css}

Comment: @Brainfeeder, I have posted a reply but it is only a half of a reply. I need to make [THIS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) customizable, or I'll feel frustrated. I'll dive into it deeper ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was solved by setting the **"path"** instead of the **"name"** parameter to controller's @RequestMapping. The answer is here: [Springboot - Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/htm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266928/springboot-resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-t)

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what sort of magic was turning the .css file into the .html one. When the server couldn't serve it (404) - the bootstrap.css was shown as an empty file. Anyway, I need to post here how the problem was solved:
I had to make paths like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" data-th-href="@{/img/ico.png}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" data-th-href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}" 
media="all">
```

and the ResourceHandler:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

this works. Also notice that in fact there is a `/static/` folder between `/resources/` and `/css/`. So, like here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Answer (score 1):

In my case the culprit was the **URL Mappings**.

I had two methods in two different controllers pointing to the same path. Usually you get an exception like this:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map
>   'studentController' method

But in my case it did not occur. So make sure that your mappings are good.
This was my mapping structure that didn't cause the exception, but made all my resources (css and js files) point to the current HTML file.

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {
  @GetMapping
  public String getRegisterStudentPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
    return "addStudent";
  }
}

@Controller
public class CourseInstanceController {
  @GetMapping(value = {"/", "/cursusoverzicht"})
  public String getCourseInstancePage(Model model) {
    // ...
    model.addAttribute("coursesInstances", coursesInstances);
    return "viewCoursesInstances";
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing for sure - we must not take over the URL path to our .css (or generated .scss) with any of our controllers. For example, this: `public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("*").setViewName("main");` was supposed to catch user's mistyped GET requests and lead the user to the main.html. However, this made my .css file unreachable by the Thymeleaf engine (th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"). It was adifferent case - no .css file at all. However, I still want to know how to implement a default controller. Smth to do w init order

Comment: Haha, that isn't nice. Default Controller to redirect mistyped requests to the main page?

Comment: Can't find how to do it with a `ViewControllerRegistry`, but doing it with a `Controller` is doable with somethink like this: `@RequestMapping(value ="/**")` inside a `Controller` right? Also check this Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346213/spring-mvc-redirecting-to-home-page-no-matter-what-link-it-is